# Online tools for generating the NULL SPACE of the matrix over Finite Field of size 2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, online-resources, matrix-equations

Is there any online tool where I just enter the values in (0,1) Finite Field of size 2 and it's give me the NULL SPACE matrix ?

I have 25x25 , 36x36 , 25x36 , 36x25 matrix.

Below is my 25 x 25 matrix

```
1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1
```

Below is my 36 x 36 matrix.

```
1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: @J.W.Perry No I have 4 matrix (25x25 , 36x36 , 25x36 , 36x25 ). So 25x25 is one matrix which will have only value (0,1) Finite Field of size 2. So now I want NULL SPACE matrix of this matrix. Is it clear please let me know ?

Comment: You might test [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NullSpace%5B%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%7D%5D) with the Nullspace[ ] function. I am not sure when it will break though. I expect it will shut you down after matrices of a certain size. Is that what you mean?

Comment: As your matrices are kinda small (not in thousands or millions), it shouldn't take you too long to do this by hand. Or, if you need to do this for many matrices, write a piece of code that does this by the usual row reduction algorithm. 25 bits fit into a single word, and with the field of two elements all the elementary row operations are just bitwise XORs and swaps. Finding the location of the most significant non-zero bit may require a loop, but you need that anyway. But you asked for on-line tools. IDK. If WA fails...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think you miss something in understanding my question. 25 x 25 means I have 25 rows and column whose value is 0 or 1. I have edited my question and put one of my matrix. Do you still think it is good to do it by hand ?

Comment: Ok my best idea at this point: Try [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/). If you are willing to register, there is a link to a cloud resource on that page. You can of course always download the open source install as well. I feel fairly certain that Sage will handle your matrices, although I have not tested the cloud resource for any restrictions.

Comment: @J.W.Perry I will try Sage and let you if I stuck. Thanks

Comment: @J.W.Perry I think if I try on Wolfram Alpha it will work. But it's giving me error that input is to long.

Comment: @eswaat Yeah I got the same result. The only way to do it would be with a pro trial, and enter as data input.

Comment: @J.W.Perry I tried in that way but it's not working somehow

Comment: I noticed the prompt for pro and enter as data input, but have never played with it. I would imagine you need to enter as m= the giant matrix, then do Nullspace[m], but I am only guessing as I have yet to use the pro feature. Did you mess with Sage yet?

Comment: @J.W.Perry not yet I just want output of 3 matrix so I don't want to install or use sage for that. but let' see

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13344/discussion-between-eswaat-and-j-w-perry)

Comment: The $36\times 36$-matrix has a similar structure with $6\times6$ blocks, and a tridiagonal block $B$. The same principles work there. Only the final constraint on $x_1$ will look different, but other sextets can be written in terms of $x_1$. No new ideas are needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an answer to the full question, but rather a response to the challenge of doing the given $25\times25$-matrix by hand. Mind you, I wouldn't touch this, if it weren't for the regular structure :-)

Let us write
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}1&1&0&0&0\\1&1&1&0&0\\0&1&1&1&0\\0&0&1&1&1\\0&0&0&1&1\end{array}\right).
$$
The given larger matrix, call it $M$, has block structure
$$
M=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}A&I&0&0&0\\I&A&I&0&0\\0&I&A&I&0\\0&0&I&A&I\\0&0&0&I&A\end{array}\right),
$$
where a $0$ denotes a $5\times5$-block of all zeros, and $I$ denotes a $5\times5$ identity matrix. We are to find the kernel of the corresponding linear mapping from $V=\Bbb{F}_2^{25}$ to itself. Write a vector $X\in V$ as column vector, also with five blocks $x_i, i=1,2,3,4,5,$ all belonging to $\Bbb{F}_2^5$:
$$
X=\left(\begin{array}{c}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\x_5\end{array}\right).
$$
The equation $MX=0$ is thus equivalent to the system
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
Ax_1&+&x_2&&&&&&&=&0,\\
x_1&+&Ax_2&+&x_3&&&&&=&0,\\
&&x_2&+&Ax_3&+&x_4&&&=&0,\\
&&&&x_3&+&Ax_4&+&x_5&=&0,\\
&&&&&&x_4&+&Ax_5&=&0.
\end{array}\right.
$$
Here a chain reaction using the four first equations allows us to write the other parts in terms of $x_1$. We immediately get:
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_2&=Ax_1,\\
x_3&=Ax_2+x_1=(I+A^2)x_1,\\
x_4&=Ax_3+x_2=A^3x_1,\\
x_5&=Ax_4+x_3=(I+A^2+A^4)x_1.
\end{aligned}
$$
The last equation then gives the constraint
$$
0=Ax_5+x_4=(A+A^5)x_1.
$$
So we have reduce the problem into determining the null space of 
$$
A+A^5=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}0&1&1&0&1\\1&1&1&0&0\\1&1&0&1&1\\0&0&1&1&1\\1&0&1&1&0\end{array}\right).
$$
We easily see that this matrix has rank three, and its null space is spanned by
$u=(1,0,1,0,1)^T$ and $v=(0,1,1,1,0)$.

The conclusion  is that the null space of $M$ is also two-dimensional. You get it in terms of $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ and $x_5$ by substituting both $u$ and $v$ in place of $x_1$ in the above formulas.